# In what sense a path integral can be approximated by the classical contribution $\exp{[\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}S_{\text{cl}}}]$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, path-integral, semiclassical, asymptotics

People often say that the amplitude $K(b,a)$ to go from $a$ to $b$ can be approximated by $$K(b,a) \sim \exp{\left[\frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}S_{\text{cl}}(b,a)\right]},\tag{1}$$
where $S_{\text{cl}}(b,a)$ is the corresponding classical action, and use this to calculate the amplitude (or partition function in some other sense) [1], paying no attention to the possible prefactor. But I want to know, in a general case, what's hidden in the '~' symbol.

In the example of a free particle, the exact path integral can be evaluated [2]:
$$
K(b, a)=\left(\frac{m}{2 \pi i \hbar\left(t_b-t_a\right)}\right)^{1 / 2} \exp \left\{\frac{i m\left(x_b-x_a\right)^2}{2 \hbar\left(t_b-t_a\right)}\right\}.\tag{2}
$$
Then it's clear that there's a function as a prefactor. **Therefore my first question is: How can we just ignore a prefactor which doesn't have to be close to $1$ when we approximate something?** What does it actually mean when we use the classical contribution to *approximate* the amplitude?

Then I think I'll just calculate the contribution from the classical path. But as Feynman said in his book, we have to provide a normalizing factor to let the path integral has a limit, which, in the case of free particle, is $A=\left(\frac{2\pi\mathrm i \hbar\epsilon}{m}\right)^{1/2}$. But **what's the normalizing factor** when I don't have to integrate over intermediate positions $x_1$, $x_2$, and so on. Or is there some other way to exactly calculate the contribution from the classical path?

---

**References**

1. [Liu, H. *String Theory and Holographic Duality*, Lec22](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-821-string-theory-and-holographic-duality-fall-2014/resources/mit8_821s15_lec22/), Eq. (5)
2. Feynman & Hibbs, *Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals*.

Comment: This is known as the semi-classical limit (WKB). It’s essentially a $\hbar\to0$ expansion. It is done by a saddle point approximation. The $\sim$ means the dominating order in  log scale. In the case of the harmonic oscillator, this checks out  since the next term is in $\ln \hbar$ (power prefactor).

Answer (score 4):

1. The expansion (1) is the WKB/[stationary phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation) for the semi-classical limit $\hbar\to 0$ (which is just the Wick-rotated version of the formula for the [method of steepest descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent)), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351072/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. The $1/\sqrt{\hbar}$ in the prefactor (2) in the propagator $$K(x_2,t_2 ; x_1,t_1) =\langle x_2,t_2 | x_1,t_1\rangle$$ is caused by the standard normalization of instantaneous position eigenstates $|x,t\rangle$, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/41914/2451).
3. Excluding the downstairs $\hbar$-dependence caused by the choice of normalization, the rest of the prefactor (2) is a  1-loop$^1$ effect from calculating a functional determinant$^2$, which is subleading/subdominant for $\hbar\to 0$ (as compared to the classical contribution).

--

$^1$ See the $\hbar$/loop expansion, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/270456/2451).

$^2$ The [functional determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant) is perhaps more apparent for the case of a harmonic oscillator, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328439/2451) Phys.SE post.